# PhoneGap HTML5 Player

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i have an Web Application is for audio recording and playing. For that i am using `html5` player.
[image: HTML5 Player]

Now I have to develope `Phonegap` `Android` App. I have used plugin (`org.apache.cordova.media`) for media purpose. but i didnt get the Audio player 
controls. How can i enable the `HTML5` Player in `Phonegap` ( in Picture)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this the same way that you're doing it for your web App. Another way is by using jQuery with html + css or phoneGap has a few Media plugins. Html5 option below. Do a google search on it, I once found a few usefull examples.

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="Audio Source, eg: music/song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   Your browser does not support the audio element.
 </audio>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try the media file opener plugin for your problem. Check the below link its very easy to integrate and you can run any type of media file using that.

**MediaFileOpener plugin :** [click here](http://github.com/markeeftb/FileOpener)